# magento white page after upgrade from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

I have upgraded **magento 1.9.1** to **1.9.2**. Locally it works fine but in the production environment I am getting white screen at checkout `(www.site.com/checkout/onepage/)`.

When I checked dev_system.log file I saw two errors.

ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: isParent  in `public_html/app/code/local/Chestnut/Menu/Block/Navigation.php` on line 165

and

Notice: Undefined variable: block  in `public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` on line 187
Notice: Undefined variable: block  in `public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php` on line 197

After reviewing responses from other users with similar issue I understand that variables and blocks have to be included in white list either manually or through script.

" Is it possible to provide me the variable and block names that has to be added in the white list or exact steps to get the variable and block names."

Comment: I think this issue because it conflict with a third party module(Chestnut/Menu)

Comment: this toolbox can fix your block/variables whitelist problem. https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox but not sure if it will fix your white page.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Magento core bug, because the core code uses the `$block` variable without checking whether is has been initialized: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L171-L187
To fix the bug navigate the line https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L174
It is empty. Place the following code to the line:

`$block = null;`

It will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. White screen - 500 internal server issue turned out to be due to memory limit.

Comment: Hi @Mage2.PRO - please never suggest modifying core code!